# Global path not changing despite newly discovered obstacle

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using move_base to generate paths based on a map & odom generated by hector_mapping. The below rviz screenshot sums up my problem quite well: essentially as the new (middle) obstacle appeared in my LiDAR's view, the global path (in green) doesn't update. It seems properly inflated (blue).

So what happens is that move_base keeps going onto the global path until it arrives too close to the obstacle, and then it backs up (recovery mode).

Any ideas why my global path isn't changing?

[image]

My yamls:

```
   global_costmap:

  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_link 
  update_frequency: 1.0

  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true

  width: 26
  height: 26
  resolution: 0.025

  map_type: costmap


local_costmap:
  global_frame: /odom
  robot_base_frame: /base_link 
  update_frequency: 1.5
  publish_frequency: 1.5
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 20.0 
  height: 20.0 
  resolution: 0.05

  map_type: costmap
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62295/global-path-not-changing-despite-newly-discovered-obstacle/) by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2013-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to fix this problem by setting a smaller path_distance_bias for my base_local_planner. Now move_base veers away from this "wrong" global path & creates a new better global path.

```
path_distance_bias: 0.15 # weighting for how much the controller should stay close to the path it was given
```

---

Originally posted by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) with karma: 341 on 2013-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Ernest: I am not sure if the solution you have provided will work in every case. Here's my take on it.

Take a look at the planner_frequency parameter at http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base I believe your navigation instance is not re-planning as the local_planner is not giving up control despite the obstacle.

On a differential drive robot, it can sometimes get difficult to balance the path and goal bias parameters to produce good behavior in all cases (in this particular instance you have found a solution by tweaking these parameters). An easier solution is to set planner_frequency to something other than 0, which forces replanning giving the local_planner a plan with a better chance of success.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on 2013-05-08**:
Hi, thanks a lot for your response, it made me discover a bunch of useful params that I had left as defaults! I've tried setting controller_frequency to non-zero values but my global path isn't recomputed - it still goes through the obstacle. I suppose it's not a big deal if the local planner avoids

**Comment by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on 2013-05-08**:
the obstacle successfully. Can you think of particular situations in which this "hack" would not work? Thanks again

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2013-05-08**:
@Ernest: I can't remember, and I use a different local planner these days. You should try changing the planner_frequency instead of controller_frequency.

**Comment by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on 2013-05-08**:
Oops yes I meant planner_frequency. I've changed it and I still have the same global paths..

**Comment by [edwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/18151/edwin/) on 2014-05-25**:
hi dear Ernest , i have exactly the same problem . is your problem solved ? , if yes , how can i force the trajectory planner to generate dynamic paths when an obstacle comes in front of robot ... ?!

if any body have any idea its my pleasure to hear them .